# Maximum likelihood using in binned data/model, missing measurement in some bins?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, monte-carlo

My apologies for this title that is likely vague, but I didn't find a better way to summarize my issue. So I'll start here with the global idea of my problem.

I have a simulation software that, given a vector of 3 parameters, creates in return a certain number of objects with different shape and sizes. The main idea is to see if, given an observation of so many objects with some statistics of their shape, I can recover the corresponding vector of parameters using Monte Carlo techniques. Because I have many objects, I average the shape statistics in smaller bins, of given object size. Here is a concrete example with a list of objects observed, where each object has a size and X_shape is the statistics derived from their shape.

```
+---------+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|  Size   | 1 | 2 | 10 | 500 |  13 |  56 |  80 |  123 |
+---------+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| X_shape | 5 | 3 |  5 |  69 |   1 |   2 |  11 |   4  |
+---------+---+---+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

The binned statistics then looks like:

```
+-------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
|             | 1 < Size <= 10 | 10 < Size <= 100 |  100 < Size  |
+-------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| X_shape_bin |              3 |                4 |          31  |
+-------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

This is what I put in my likelihood, that assumes a Gaussian distribution:

$Log(L) =-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i}^{\rm Nbins\ =\ 3}  \frac{({\rm X\_shape\_bin_{data}} (i) - {\rm X\_shape\_bin_{model}} (i))^2}{\sigma(i)^2}$

where $ \rm X\_shape\_bin_{data}$ is the statistics I observed, and the $ \rm X\_shape\_bin_{model}$ the statistics from the models based on the parameter space sampled in the Monte Carlo sampler.

This works well when both the data have a measurement in each size bin, but it happens sometimes that the statistics extracted from a given model looks like this:

```
+-------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
|             | 1 < Size <= 10 | 10 < Size <= 100 |  100 < Size  |
+-------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| X_shape_bin |              - |                - |          3   |
+-------------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
```

In that case, the Likelihood will only be computed based on the last bin, and therefore be artificially higher, while this model should actually be penalized because only a single bin has been included.

There is no way I can predict the missing data unfortunately, so I am looking for a way to penalize these cases.

I hope this is somehow clear, and hope you might know how to handle these cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that some data are missing? Should the sum in all bins be equal to a certain number $N$? Just a hunch: maybe you can calculate likelihood multiplying not only probabilities of certain data being in certain bins but probability of certain data not being in certain bins.

Comment: I know the data is missing because I am measuring it from the model. The output of the model gives a me a list of objects, with their associated statistics on their shape. If the model did not produce any objects of size between 1 and 10, while my observed data have some, then I can not compare the statistics in that bin. The number of objects produced per bin depends on the set of parameters used for the model, and on some random effects. But indeed, your suggestion might work, I'll test it.

Comment: Please, let me know whether it works -- I'm curious

Comment: That worked, but that makes the global inference very sensitive to the choice of the bin size. I have to think a bit more how to solve this.